# How to reflect new user profile changes in OidcUser?

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

How can I update the user profile changes like name, locale and more after Spring Security's OidcUserService has fetched it from KeyCloak IDP when the end user completes the authentication and authorization flow i.e. I updated the attributes of the user profile in KeyCloak but the data in OidcUser was not updated because a request was not made to the /userinfo endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can

- configure keycloak to include whatever claim you like in access-token
- configure spring-security to have security context populated with an `Authentication` instance based on access-token claims (either with a JWT decoder or token introspection)

You'll find sample resource-server configuration here : https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Setting the **Base URL** field [http://base-url-app/oauth2/authorization/login-client] in the Client used by app in the authorization flow, which allows to show the Back Button back in the profile screen and thus redirect the user to the authorization flow.

[image: See bottom of image, field Base URL]